# Cycle notation: Inverse of $(1348)$ in $S_9$ ( Find the mistake)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles, algebraic-cycles

> Find inverse of $(1348)$ in $S_9.$

Here, we are using the cycle notation.

Clearly, the inverse is $(8431).$ Since $(1348)\circ (8431)$ will have
$$8\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 $$
$$4\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 $$
$$3\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 $$
$$1\rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 1 $$

So $(1348)\circ (8431)=e$

But we also have $(1348)\circ(1348)\circ (1348)\circ (1348)=e.$

So the inverse of $(1348)$ is $(1348)^3=(1348)\circ(1348)\circ (1348)=(8134).$

$$1\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 $$
$$3\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 1 $$
$$4\rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 $$
$$8\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$$

---

Clearly $(8134)$ is not the inverse of $(1348).$
What mistake have I made?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: I think I got the mistake, so after $(1348)^3,$ we get
$$1\rightarrow 8 $$
$$3\rightarrow 1 $$
$$4\rightarrow 3 $$
$$8\rightarrow 4 $$

So, the answer is $$(1\rightarrow 8\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 3)=(1843)=(8431)$$

Comment: The third power $(1348)(1348)(1348)=(1843)$ which is equal to $(8431)$. I don't know what you did wrong when computing that power.

Comment: The problem is that $(1348)^3 = (1843)$, you have calculated it right but you have confused the notation. $1$ goes to $8$, $8$ goes to $4$, $4$ goes to $3$ and $3$ goes to $1$, that's eactly $(1843)$, not $(8134)$

Comment: Looking at those four lines near the end: May be you just don't yet understand how to turn a permutation into cycle notation? If $\alpha=(1348)$ then, indeed, $\alpha^3(1)=8$, $\alpha^3(3)=1$, $\alpha^3(4)=3$ and $\alpha^3(8)=4$. This means that $\alpha^3=(1843)$.

Comment: so at the end we get 
1--> 8
3--> 1
4--->3
8--->4

Then we use cycle notation, we get 1-->8--->4--->3-->1
oh I see, I got the mistake

Comment: Good @SunainaPati!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here $1 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 8$ is the result of applying the permutation $3$ times.

So this means in $(1348)^3$, $1$ is mapped to $8$. Reading the others, we get $3\mapsto 1, 4\mapsto 3, 8\mapsto 4.$

If we convert that to this notation, we get $(1348)^3 = (1843),$ which is the same as $(8413).$

When you wrote $(8134)$, I think you just read the right-most numbers, which is not the right way to interpret it.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it! Can you once see my edited part of my question if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: @SunainaPati It is.